Lubuntu 20.04.6 package control and package center errors
On Lubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
sudo apt install gnome control center
produces:
[sudo] password for markn:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package control
E: Unable to locate package center
Can anyone on here suggest a method of getting these two errors fixed?

FYI:  You're aware that Lubuntu 20.04 LTS was a flavor of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and came with 3 years of supported life? (refer https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ reaching the end of its three year supported life) with 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu base but not flavors. You're still on-topic here with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS questions though (even if using LXQt)

Your command told the system to install three packages; gnome, control and center which does not match what you indicated you wanted. A space character is a delimiter, ie. tells the system where a package ends & the next option/package is. As only the GNOME package exists; that was the only package available for install; you likely intended gnome-control-center | 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4.1       | focal-security  where you'll note the package name varies significant; ie. NO SPACES and HYPHENS.

For lubuntu you do not need this package.

Your command told the system to install three packages; gnome, control and center which does not match what you indicated you wanted.
A space character is a delimiter, ie. tells the system where a package ends & the next option/package is.
As only the GNOME package exists; that was the only package available for install; you likely intended
gnome-control-center | 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4.1       | focal-security          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x

where you'll note the package name varies significant; ie. NO SPACES and HYPHENS.
gnome-control-center is the name of a valid package you appear to want.

Package names need to be exactly; including case.  I'm not sure that package will help you with a Lubuntu/LXQt system anyway; but you gave no reason why you wanted it.... ie. I'm using Lubuntu's LXQt desktop currently, and if I try and run it I only get the error "Running gnome-control-center is only supported under GNOME and Unity, exiting" ie. it does nothing; requiring me to logout & login again using GNOME (which is actually installed on my system; it's useful if I was using a GNOME session, but not LXQt)
